# How to append text based on matching td contents

Tags: jquery, html-table, append, match

I have this table in which I want to check for matching content in td's. If there is a match, a HTML-character must be shown in another td. In the example below, the last td should contain a checkmark if the first and third td have matching content:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td id="star_psd">3</td><td>&nbsp;stars where&nbsp;</td>
  <td id="need_psd">5</td><td>&nbsp;are needed</td>
  <td id="check_psd"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td id="star_nto">2</td><td>&nbsp;stars where&nbsp;</td>
  <td id="need_nto">2</td><td>&nbsp;are needed</td>
  <td id="check_nto"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td id="star_pmi">0</td><td>&nbsp;stars where&nbsp;</td>
  <td id="need_pmi">2</td><td>&nbsp;are needed</td>
  <td id="check_pmi"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

So, only the td with id check_nto should contain the checkmark.

Amongst other code, I have tried the following:

```
  var match_psd = $("star_psd").text();
   if (match_psd == $("need_psd").text()) {
      $("#check_psd").append("&#9989;");
   }
```

.. but it's not working; the checkmarks are always displayed in all check-mark tds. What am I doing wrong here? Please advise! Suggestions for doing this another (cleaner) way are welcome as well.

Comment: As a minimum you need to fix your selectors and change `$("star_psd")` to `$("#star_psd")` and `$("need_psd")` to `$("#need_psd")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that your selectors are incorrect as they are missing the `#` prefix for matching an `id` attribute.

With regard to your goal, the simplest way to achieve this is to put common classes on all the relevant `td` elements. Then you can loop through every 'check' cell to set the `html()` based on the comparison of the stars and the needed stars for the row. Try this:

```js
$('.check').html(function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
  return parseInt($row.find('.star').text(), 10) == parseInt($row.find('.need').text(), 10) ? '&#9989;' : '';
});
```

```css
td { padding: 0 3px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="star" id="star_psd">3</td>
    <td>stars where</td>
    <td class="need" id="need_psd">5</td>
    <td>are needed</td>
    <td class="check" id="check_psd"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="star" id="star_nto">2</td>
    <td>stars where</td>
    <td class="need" id="need_nto">2</td>
    <td>are needed</td>
    <td class="check" id="check_nto"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="star" id="star_pmi">0</td>
    <td>stars where</td>
    <td class="need" id="need_pmi">2</td>
    <td>are needed</td>
    <td class="check" id="check_pmi"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="star" id="star_foo">100</td>
    <td>stars where</td>
    <td class="need" id="need_foo">100</td>
    <td>are needed</td>
    <td class="check" id="check_foo"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that I removed the `&nbsp;` usage in your HTML. Use CSS to add padding if required instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another less dense and more explanatory implementation of what Rory did could be something like the following:

```
<table>

  <tr>
    <td class="numberOfStars" id="star_psd">3</td><td>&nbsp;stars where&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="requiredStars" id="need_psd">5</td><td>&nbsp;are needed</td>
    <td class="theCheckmark" id="check_psd"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="numberOfStars" id="star_nto">2</td><td>&nbsp;stars where&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="requiredStars" id="need_nto">2</td><td>&nbsp;are needed</td>
    <td class="theCheckmark" id="check_nto"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="numberOfStars" id="star_pmi">0</td><td>&nbsp;stars where&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="requiredStars" id="need_pmi">2</td><td>&nbsp;are needed</td>
    <td class="theCheckmark" id="check_pmi"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

... and then ...

```
var rowCounter = 0;

$('tr').each(function() {

   rowCounter += 1;
   var numOfStars = parseInt($(this).find('.numberOfStars').text());
   var reqStars = parseInt($(this).find('.requiredStars').text());
   var check = '&#10004;';

   console.log('~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Row Number:'+rowCounter+' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~');
   console.log('Number of stars: ' +numOfStars);
   console.log('Required stars: ' +reqStars);

   if(numOfStars < reqStars) {
      console.log('Number of stars DOES NOT meet the number of required stars');
   } else {
     console.log('Number of stars meets the number of required stars');
     $(this).find('.theCheckmark').html(check);
   }

   console.log('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n');

});
```

... for each tr:

- find and store the number of stars in a variable
- find and store the number of required stars in another variable
- create a variable that contains the check-mark symbol
- perform a comparison between the number of stars and the number of required stars
- depending on the result of the comparison, show a corresponding message and put/omit the check-mark into the check-mark container

  *(Notice the parseInt which turns the text of each td into an integer and it is necessary to perform the comparison correctly. Otherwise you would be comparing text characters, not numbers)*

Rory's solution is correct